# Enable Cloud download option in Windows 10

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10, cloud, reset

PC Reset is not working from Recovery and not able to use the option of CLOUD Download

Comment: Not programming related - this should be on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "cloud download" Feature is not enabled then run the following command in command prompt

```
reagentc /enable
```